# Layer 3 Device ICMP behavior and impact on tracert

Tags: windows, icmp, traceroute

Is it possible to configure a layer 3 device to set the TTL of all ICMP echo request packets to zero and not send out ICMP Time Exceeded message ? If so, wouldn't this make it impossible for tracert to finish for any path that got routed through it ?

Comment: Yes, that's technically possible.